# About a post in AskUbuntu that received a downvote

Tags: discussion, downvoting

Yesterday I posted in Ask Ubuntu a question about `dnsmasq`, and it was a large post with all important details, what I have tried already, the error messages, and it became really long - more than I usually see in Ask Ubuntu.

Today, some minutes ago, I deleted the first post and did a new one, a lot more summarized, because I think it is better like that: [dnsmasq configuration for TFTP + ProxyDHCP in Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506431/dnsmasq-configuration-for-tftp-proxydhcp-in-ubuntu-server-22-04-3-lts)

Some minutes later, I received a downvote and I don't know why.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in that new post?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your post. The downvoter should have added a comment justifying their vote, potentially leading you to clarify or improve something in your post. However, unfortunately, there are times that someone may downvote a post without leaving any feedback. In that case there is not much you can do. You just accept that. Since I don't see something obviously wrong with your question, I have upvoted it to even the downvote.

Comment: I did the same - so now it's +1.